# How to sort an Alphanumeric column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have grouped by on a column. I want that columns output in the sorted format.

```
select distinct pages from test  order by 1;
```

Below is my Output:

```
hello-1-new-base.html
hello-10-zero-fees.html
hello-2-visual-indicator.html
hello-3-positive-language.html
hello-4-processing-fees.html
hello-5-credit10.html
hello-6-credit25.html
hello-7-new-language.html
hello-8-positive-negative.html
hello-9-acknowledge.html
```

Expected Output:

```
hello-1-new-base.html
hello-2-visual-indicator.html
hello-3-positive-language.html
hello-4-processing-fees.html
hello-5-credit10.html
hello-6-credit25.html
hello-7-new-language.html
hello-8-positive-negative.html
hello-9-acknowledge.html
hello-10-zero-fees.html
```

Comment: @shadow can u please share a relevant answer link.I'm am not able to find it.

Comment: It's on the top of this page.